# Sharing entities between features in Flutter clean architecture

Tags: flutter, model, entity, clean-architecture, flutter-bloc

I am trying to develop a small application in Flutter with BloC state management and get_it dependency injection while using clean architecture.

I currently have developed a feature which makes an API request to an endpoint and maps that information to a model which is then accessed through bloc builder state as an entity.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7V_P6dovixg) guide to understand clean architecture so my project is structured the same way.

Below is how I am defining the entity in the presentation layer and assigning it the values from bloc state:

```
static LoginEntity? loginEntity = const LoginEntity();
loginEntity = state.loginEntity![0];
```

In my bloc state I have loginEntity defined:

```
abstract class RemoteLoginDetailsState extends Equatable {
  const RemoteLoginDetailsState({this.loginEntity});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [loginEntity!];
}
```

In my api service.g.dart file my request is made and mapped to the model:

```
    LoginModel value = LoginModel.fromJson(_result.data!);
    final httpResponse = HttpResponse([value], _result);
    return httpResponse;
```

I am having issues understanding how I can use the information obtained from the API response in one feature in other features while adhering to clean architecture.

How do we properly share information from entities after it has been mapped?

Say I have a login feature which has a name object and I obtain the value of that name object and map it to my model. How should I then access the value of the name object in another feature while adhering to clean architecture?

I am aware maybe it can be done through state by passing the state from one feature to another but I am unsure if this still adheres to clean architecture and how exactly it should be done.

I understand DTO's can also be used but I always thought they should only be used for transferring objects in the same feature not from one feature to another.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have a login feature which has a name object and I obtain the value of that name object and map it to my model. How should I then access the value of the name object in another feature while adhering to clean architecture?

For classic scenarios/feature, I will suggest you to fetch a fresh data from API for each feature and display or manipulate it as you want for the specific feature. It will ensure that the data is up to date.

If the data is persistant and does not change, you should consider save in local storage

If you update the data, you should have an endpoint to do that.

With Stream you could catch the update data and have reactive UI

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So say I have a login endpoint and also a landing page endpoint but I have already made the request for the login page. Are you saying to define the same request code in the landing page feature to get up to date information and define 2 models and entities which would be login and landing for example? This would result in duplicate code but is this the correct way it should be done in clean architecture? Thanks.

Comment: If it is the same endpoint called, the model should be the same because it is the strict representation of what you get from the API. The request code will be called with the same repository class (no code duplication) but perhaps from a different controller associated with the feature.

The entities can be different depending on the business logic of your features. So if the data you want to display is the same, you can use the same entity. Reusability is common sense

Comment: Another approach is the definition of the feature. It may not be useful to have a dedicated feature landing page that only shows the same data as the previous feature, the view could be included in the login feature

finally, nothing prevents passing the entity to the next feature but it still depends on the business logic of the features. 

It is my point of view, hope it will help you

Comment: The endpoint and model are the same. Are you saying to call the repository class from one feature to another to avoid code duplication then or make a shared repository class? I just used the landing page as an example but take into consideration this page would use another endpoint too. It would use the login endpoint and another endpoint so 2 endpoints.

Comment: the "controller" of the feature can call any repository. In your case it will call login repository, and maybe your endpoint that is in an other repository. For exemple, if you have to update an user activity everywhere in the app, the activity repository will be called in other features.
Project tree architecture is just an organisation, the most important is Separation of Concerns and Reusability